# Notification в Windows 8.1

Tags: python, python-3.x

Делаю небольшую програмку которая работает как демон. Но вот не могу найти как сделать оповещение в Windwos 8.1.

Как вариант смотрел на [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921203/how-to-create-a-system-tray-popup-message-with-python-windows)(pywin32), но такой вариант мне не очень подходит.
Или нативно не получится? Придется использовать:

- wxPython
- PyGTK
- PyQT

Для моей програмки это слишком жирно :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наоборот, используя какую-нибудь из перечисленных библиотек, вы облегчите себе жизнь. Например, пример для wx:

```
import wx, sys
import wx.adv

import time

app = wx.App()


class TestTaskBarIcon(wx.adv.TaskBarIcon):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.adv.TaskBarIcon.__init__(self)

        self.Bind(wx.adv.EVT_TASKBAR_LEFT_UP, lambda e: (self.RemoveIcon(),sys.exit()))

        i = 0

        while True:
            wx.adv.NotificationMessage("Yo?", "Alarm " + str(i)).Show()
            time.sleep(10 * 60)
            i += 10


icon = TestTaskBarIcon()
app.MainLoop()
```

Каждые десять минут в трее вылазит сообщение. Можно пойти по пути создания маленького окна поверх всех остальных. wxWidgets для Python 3 называется [ProjectPhoenix](https://wiki.wxpython.org/ProjectPhoenix).

Comment: Спасибо, да, я это уже понял. Да вот теперь думаю, на чем легче будет сделать, смотрю на wx и qt, примеры из wx кажутся более понятными. Вот еще думаю переделать приложение чтоб оно крутилось в трее, с небольшой менюшкой.

Comment: @ВладимирSeos-Lab, не сказать, что тема всплывающих сообщений заезжена, но для wxWidgets (Py2) мне попадались даже маленькие библиотеки специально для этого.

Comment: В общем спасибо! Буду разбираться.